# How do horizontally center a fixed navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have looked around and cannot find out how to horizontally center my fixed navigation bar.

If you can could you show me how to and explain why.

Thanks.

```css
#nav {
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Product Sans;
  font-size: 0;
}
#nav li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li>stack</li>
  <li>over</li>
  <li>flow</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to center align the li items inside the ul

so the CSS will be

```
<style>

#nav{
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Product Sans;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align:center;
  padding-left:0px;
}
#nav li{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}


</style>
```

And keep the html without any change

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `text-align: center;` to the **#nav**, like this:

```
<style>
 #nav{
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Product Sans;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center; /* <--- */
}
</style>
```